# openpyxl create a function that references a cell in another sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I just started working with openpyxl a couple of days ago and its a great library.  However, the documentation seems to be sparse for advanced features.  I have a couple of issues.

1. openpyxl seems to change the formula that I insert to a lower case which results in an unknown reference from excel.
2. furthermore, i changed the name of the sheet to accomidate the lowercase and still found a #NAME? error in the cell where the reference was at.

Can someone please show me how or where to find out how to reference a cell from another sheet in openpyxl

```
import openpyxl.Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
#shows up lowercase with name error in excel
ws.cell('A1).value = "$'Sheet'.E7 + 123"
#still shows a name error in excel
ws.cell('A2').value = "$'sheet'.E7 + 123"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title ='NewSheet'
ws.cell('E7').value = 7

ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.cell('A1').value = "=NewSheet!E7 + 123"

wb.save( filename = 'temp2.xlsx' )
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a google colab example with a more recent `openpyxl`. Works fine, but had to change some syntax . https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P4IK7tgo2BT3-h6KG-9wYkT37wZ4mBJh

Answer (score 4):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, utils
wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title ='NewSheet'
ws.cell('E7').value = 7

ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.cell('A1').value = f"={utils.quote_sheetname(ws.title)}!E7 + 123"

wb.save( filename = 'temp2.xlsx' )
```

The problem with the previous answer is that it's dependant on the title of the sheet being 'NewSheet'. Using `quote_sheetname()`controls that.

Comment: Found your answer later, but in my case in works in such way:

ws.cell('E7').value = f"='{ws.title}'!$E7+123"

I use both ! and $,